# Error: Cannot read property 'createRouter' of undefined

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

```
import { createApp } from "vue";
import VueRouter from "vue-router";

const app = createApp({});

app.use(VueRouter);
const routes=[
    {
        path:'/dashboard',
        name:'Dashboard',
        component:()=>import("../view/dashboard.vue")
    }
];
const routers=VueRouter.createRouter ({
    history: VueRouter.createWebHashHistory(),
    routes,
})

app.use(routers)

app.mount('#app')

// export default router
```

[image]

As the picture, what's wrong.
There is no error when I executed NPM run serve
[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you're using `vue-router v4.x` you could do :

```
import { createApp } from "vue";
import {createRouter, createWebHashHistory} from "vue-router";

const app = createApp({});


const routes=[
    {
        path:'/dashboard',
        name:'Dashboard',
        component:()=>import("../view/dashboard.vue")
    }
];
const routers=createRouter ({
    history: createWebHashHistory(),
    routes,
})

app.use(routers);


app.mount('#app')
```

Comment: please share the file `Utils.js`